# mass animate shape layers like the attached .gif

Tags: animation, adobe-after-effects

[image]I want to animate each shape layer like the two on the attached gif image. To do this manually will take forever. I have tried an animation preset but it saves the position meaning they all animate but at the same start point and end up at the same end point.

[image]

Comment: How about making a particle system, putting them on an initial position and after that let them fall at diferent rates, or something like that?

Comment: Is it the positioning or the timing that you're struggling with? And do you want them to come up randomly or in some defined order?

Comment: when you imported from illustrator, did you import using 'retain layer sizes'? If so try re-importing without. Without retaining layer sizes each layer should be the size of the whole composition so any position animations will be relative to the composition not the shape.. i think

Comment: I want them to all individually animate like a Mexican wave, from left to right.

Comment: Okay and are you struggling with the timing or the positioning? Also what do you mean by "Animation Preset?" Are these Pre-comps? Maybe include a screenshot of your layers.

Comment: struggling with the positioning. animation preset (you can apply an animation preset to a layer > animation > apply animation preset).  Not sure how to upload a screenshot, but I have 200ish layers building that image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding what you did and where you're stuck then think this is what you should do. This isn't exactly how I'd have approached it from the start but think based on where you're already at should work for you.

1. Apply the preset at the very start of all layers that need to have the animation
2. With all layers still selected tap <kbd>U</kbd> so it shows the animation duration in the Timeline
3. Move the Time Indicator to the end of the Preset Animation
4. Temporarily trim all of your animations using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> (think its same on Mac but not positive)
5. Then go to Animation > Keyframe Assistant > Sequence Layers
6. Extend back out each layer so they stay visible after appearing.